# How to connect two wireless routers by powerlines

Tags: router, dhcp, ip-address, static-ip, access-point

To extend the wireless range I bought a pair of powerlines. So one of them is connected to the main wireless router which is provided by ISP company. And the other side of the powerline is connected to a D-Link (DIR-615) wireless router.

The second router does not provide internet. Not even by Ethernet. I was told that I have to disable the DHCP on the second one. and enter the first's routers IP as the getway. I tried to do it but I requires the IP address and Subnet mask that the ISP provided. But I never had that.

So anyway can you just tell me how I can connect these two routers. Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of any valid reason to implement powerline IP in a professional environment. If you have encountered such an environment please update your question to explain *why* you need to implement this solution, and *how it fits into a professional production environment*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second is simply relaying off of the first one, the IP/Subnet/Default Gateway would be stuff supplied by the first router. Give it an address outside of the scope DHCP can give, subnet should be the same that DHCP supplies, and Default Gateway would be the address of the first router.

Comment: Thanks for your post.  What about primary DSN address? [Screenshot](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ixs58y&s=5)

Comment: You can use the same as your default gateway, as everything would be pushed through that router. You could also see what the primary router is being configured to use, and then copy that information, but then you would have to update it if your ISP ever changed their DNS servers.

Comment: Thanks. I connected to the primary router and changed the DHCP to 192.168.0.3 so 192.168.0.1 is its own ip and 192.168.0.2 is for the new router. Is that correct? but in the new router I tired to setup internet connection. (see the attached screenshot is last comment please). So I put 192.168.0.2 in the first box, 255.255.255.0 in second and 192.168.0.1 for the geteway and and the same for DNS. But it gives error and says invalid ip address, pointing to the first box.  any idea?

Comment: The primary should be left at 192.168.0.1. It is the default gateway. The second should be setup with an IP of 192.168.0.2, subnet of 255.255.255.0 (to match the primary), default gateway of 192.168.0.1, and a default DNS of 192.168.0.1. Nothing should have to be changed on the primary in regards to DHCP/internal network settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how "a pair of powerlines" will "exted the wireless range" but I'm going on the assumption that you mean Ethernet cables, If this is incorrect please comment below.

If you are wanting to bridge the wireless signals (i.e. make two wireless access points appear as one) [DDWRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) may be a good solution to make your life easier. And there are [several posts](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Bridging) on how to use a router [flashed with DDWRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Installation) to [extend the wireless range of another](http://www.howtogeek.com/56810/how-to-extend-your-wireless-network-with-dd-wrt/).